# SELECT against stored procedure SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

`SELECT Val from storedp_Value` within the query editor of SQL Server Management Studio, is this possible?

**UPDATE**

I tried to create a temp table but it didn't seem to work hence why I asked here.

```
CREATE TABLE #Result
(
batchno_seq_no int
)
INSERT #Result EXEC storedp_UPDATEBATCH
SELECT * from #Result
DROP TABLE #Result
RETURN
```

Stored Procedure UpdateBatch

```
delete from batchno_seq;
insert into batchno_seq default values;
select @batchno_seq= batchno_seq_no from batchno_seq
RETURN @batchno_seq
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I call it from the query window?

**UPDATE #2**

Ok, I'd appreciate help on this one, direction or anything - this is what I'm trying to achieve.

```
 select batchno_seq from (delete from batchno_seq;insert into batchno_seq default values;
 select *  from batchno_seq) BATCHNO 
 INTO TEMP_DW_EKSTICKER_CLASSIC
```

This is part of a larger select statement. Any help would be much appreciated. Essentially this SQL is broken as we've migrated for Oracle.

Comment: No it's not possible. You should use functions if that is a requirement.

Comment: @NenadZivkovic I need to DELETE and INSERT though, which from what I've read isn't possible.

Comment: Or you can use 'workaround' by creating temp table, inserting results from SP in it, and then select from temp table.

Comment: DELETE and INSERT what and where? Please provide more info and examples in the question, and maybe we can easier come to a solution.

Comment: What error are you receiving in your example? How is it not working?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, no.  To select from a stored procedure you can do the following:

```
declare @t table (
    -- columns that are returned here
);

insert into @t(<column list here>)
    exec('storedp_Value');
```

If you are using the results from a stored procedure in this way *and* you wrote the stored procedure, seriously consider changing the code to be a view or user defined function.  In many cases, you can replace such code with a simpler, better suited construct.

Answer (score 5):

This is not possible in sql server, you can insert the results into a temp table and then further query that

```
CREATE TABLE #temp ( /* columns */ )

INSERT INTO #temp ( /* columns */ )
EXEC sp_MyStoredProc

SELECT * FROM #temp
WHERE 1=1

DROP TABLE #temp
```

Or you can use `OPENQUERY` but this requires setting up a linked server, the SQL is

```
SELECT * FROM (ThisServer, 'Database.Schema.ProcedureName <params>')
```

Comment: You don't have to repeat the columns again in the 'INSERT INTO' part, SQL will fill the table without specifying them explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

The best article (in my opinion) about all possible methods for sharing data between stored procedures in SQL Server you can find here: http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Change 'Return'

```
delete from batchno_seq;   
insert into batchno_seq default values;
select @batchno_seq= batchno_seq_no from batchno_seq
RETURN @batchno_seq
```

to 'Select'

```
delete from batchno_seq;   
insert into batchno_seq default values;
select @batchno_seq= batchno_seq_no from batchno_seq
SELECT @batchno_seq
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach

```
select * into new_table  from (select t1.col1,t1.col2,..
from table1 t1 
union 
select t2.cola,t2.colb,..
from table2 t2) as union_table
```

Answer (score 0):

I MUST be missing something.

Since your stored procedure does not return a result set, and instead returns an integer, using the RETURN functionality of stored procs, you simply CANNOT INSERT into ANY table (since there isn't any result set coming back, at all).

BUT, you can (assuming that this is done iteratively, and not over a set) simply store the return value into a local variable, and insert that variable's value into whatever table is necessary.

However, if you simply want to return the value in the results of a Query Window in SSMS, doing the INSERT and SELECTING is overkill.
It seems to me like THIS would suffice (in a query window):

```
DECLARE @RetVal INT = 0;

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
EXEC @RetVal = storedp_UPDATEBATCH;
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
SELECT @RetVal;
  --OR
  --PRINT @RetVal;
```

If this is way far off base, please provide the DDL for "batchno_seq", maybe I can be of better assistance that way.

Cheers!

Comment: FTR, I concur with @GordonLinoff, in this case your "Batch Stored Procedure" would be implemented  much simpler as a Scalar UDF (again, assuming that this isn't acting on a SET)